# How could I do big intersection with single $s?

Tags: math-mode

I want to obtain similar result given by,

```
\[
\bigcap_{n}J_{n}
\]
```

by using some function between single `$` i.e. `$ function $`. Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: Just use `\displaystyle\bigcap`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You probably want `$\bigcup\limits_{n}J_{n}$`, but the result is not good as it enlarges too much the height of the line.

Comment: @Sigur No. That will produce too big a symbol.

Comment: @egreg, you are right. The OP wants similar result not necessarily the same size.

Comment: @egreg +1 but you mean `\bigcap` not `\bigcup`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "canonical" way to get the limit under the operator, in this case `\bigcap`, is to use `\limits`:

```
$\bigcap\limits_{n} J_{n}$
```

This has a drawback, though. Consider the following example, where the definitions of `\1`, `\2` and `\3` are just to make up some text around the symbol. Note that the first way is what's commonly used in mathematical publications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\1{some text }\def\2{and other text }
\def\3{\1\2\1\2\1\2\1\2\1\2\1\2\1\2\1\2}

\begin{document}

\section{Good}

\3 $\bigcap_n J_{n}$ \3

\section{Bad}

\3 $\bigcap\limits_n J_{n}$ \3

\section{Ugly}

\3 $\displaystyle\bigcap\limits_n J_{n}$ \3

\end{document}
```

In the "Good" case, the lines are uniformly spaced; in the "Bad" case the line below the symbol is irregularly spaced. The "Ugly" case needs no explanation.

[image]

Comment: The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly! `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg A homage to Sergio Leone (and to Clint Eastwood, of course).

Comment: They have both done a lot of good for film! (Oh, well, this is starting to get off-topic.)

Comment: [Recommended soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFa1-kciCb4). `:)`

Comment: -1 for not going [`\def\1{15 points is a lot of rep. We're gonna have to earn it.}`](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060196/trivia?item=qt0424815)

Answer (score 1):

The `scalerel` package will let you scale the symbol to a desired size.  After showing the standard LaTeX approaches, last two lines are `\scalerel` to a target-symbol size, and the last line is `\scaleto` an absolute size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\[
\bigcap_{n}J_{n}
\]

\centering
inline $\bigcap_{n}J_{n}$

displaystyle inline $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}J_{n}$

scalerel size of $J_n^2$: inline $\scalerel*{\bigcap}{J_n^2}_{n}J_{n}$

scaleto 3ex: inline $\scaleto{\bigcap}{3ex}_{n}J_{n}$

\end{document}
```

[image]